# Disperse markers with multiple attributes?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, representation

I am familiar with using the `disperse markers tool` to disperse overlapping points in ArcMap (v. 10.7.1), but for some reason, if the symbology of my points has multiple attributes (e.g. coloured by group with symbol size varying based on count), I am unable to create a representation (which is required to disperse markers). Below is my workflow, which works when my symbology is determined by `categories` or `quantities`, but not when using `multiple attributes`.

1. Import shapefile into ArcMap 10.7.1
2. Move the shapefile into a file geodatabase
3. Change symbology (this is where I change symbology to have multiple attributes)
4. Create a representation (a. Right-click on the shapefile in the geodatabase in the Table of Contents window, b. Click Convert Symbology to Representation, c.   Name your representation, d.    Click Convert)
5. Use the disperse markers tool (a.   Choose your input, b.   Set the minimum spacing, c. Click Environments, d.  Expand Cartography, e.  Set the reference scale (input the scale of your map), f.   Click OK)

Essentially, I cannot complete step 4 if my point symbology is displayed using multiple attributes (i.e. the "Convert Symbology to Representation" option does not show up when I right-click the representation). Is there a way to fix this/another way to disperse in this scenario?

I'd really like to resolve this issue so I don't have to re-create my entire map in R.

Answer (score 0):

Make a new attribute column that's a combination of the multiple fields you want to use. Then you can apply the normal workflow for dispersed markers with single symbology.

For example, if currently your data looks like this:

| Name | Field1 | Field2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MyPlace | A | 123 |
| YourPlace | B | 345 |

Your new data would look like:
| Name | Field1 | Field2 | Field3|
|------|--------|--------|-------|
| MyPlace | A | 123 | A_123 |
| YourPlace | B | 345 | B_345 |

And your symbology is based off of Field3 instead of Field1 and Field2.